# Struts2 select tag with 2 different values

Tags: struts2

I have a list with 2 properties name and prefix (from SQL), where name is the language name and prefix is the language identifier composed of 2 letters.

And I want to make something like:

```
<select>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="uk">English UK</option>
</select>
```

I know how to do that in this way: `<s:select list="#{'en':'English', 'fr':'French', 'uk':'English UK'}"/>`

But how to display the results if we have a list from database, for example: `<s:select list="languages.name"/>`

Is is possible in Struts2 s:select tag?

Comment: Have you looked at the select tag docs?

Comment: use `listKey` and `listValue`. for details refer to doc. [Select-Tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/select.html)

Comment: I tried already, but it doesn't showing what I want, maybe I don't use it properly, and that's why I asked for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how this should work.I suppose you have a `ArrayList` of some object and this object have two properties `name` and `prefix`

So In your action class you have a ArryList something like

```
List<LanguageObject> languageList;
```

which is being populated form the DB. All you need to have following entry in your JSP

```
<s:select name="language" list="languageList"  label="Select a country" listKey="prefix"
listValue="name" />
```

where prefix and name are the 2 properties being defined in your object.

Comment: As always you give clear and good answers, thanks for the help, now is working :)